# How to generate different random values at each subprocess during a multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, random, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I need to generate a different random value at each sub-process but I realized that this local variable is rewritten or shared between each sub-process. See the example below to understand the problem I am facing:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(i):
    i2 = i**2
    random_variable = np.round(np.random.normal(), 3)
    return i2, random_variable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.map(func, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        print(result)
```

**output:**

```
[(1, -0.122), (4, -0.122), (9, -0.122), (16, -0.122), (25, -0.122)]
```

What could be the reason of this output? And how can I generate a different random variable at each sub-process?

Comment: Perhaps you could try: `np.random.seed(i)` as the first line of `def func()` so that each process has a different random seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each call to `func()` is in its own process, it needs to have its own seed to the `random` functions:

```py
def func(i):
    np.random.seed(i)
    i2 = i**2
    random_variable = np.round(np.random.normal(), 3)
    return i2, random_variable
```